# AcceptSecurityContext (Kerberos) returns SEC_E_LOGON_DENIED

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to write a simple application that performs Kerberos authentication (no mutual authentication for now).

The operating system is Windows server 2003, standard edition.
I have setup Active directory and created an SPN using setspn tool.

AcquireCredentialsHandle returns SEC_E_OK both on client and on server.

InitializeSecurityContext on client side returns SEC_E_OK.

AcceptSecurityContext on server side returns SEC_E_LOGON_DENIED.

I am sure there's nothing wrong in my code since the same behaviour I see when using the sample application from the following MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dvdarchive/bb985043.aspx

So I guess there is something wrong in my setup. But I can't find out what. Maybe I have missed something in SPN setup? Any help is appreciated.

Regards, David.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the problem was the following:

Say, your computer name is COMP, domain NetBios name is DOMAIN, the SPN you want to register is MyService/COMP.

"setspn -A MyService/COMP COMP" command registers the SPN for SYSTEM account! And when your process which belongs to another account (say Administrator) wants to act as a server for that SPN, it understandabaly fails.

You may either run your server as SYSTEM (google for how to do it) or (which is better) register the SPN for administrator (or any other) account using the following command: setspn -A MyService/COMP DOMAIN\Administrator

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The scenario above should never happen. If you enter the wrong SPN it should fail both ends. Or pass both ends. It should never pass client end and fail server end. Plus I don't want to setspn anything or register anything. Is David the same user as Davatuk?

Comment: Does this pass BOTH use-cases?

Comment: @cashcow:  The answer does indeed make sense.  The SPN is correct, which is the reason why you can AcquireCredials.  However, when the ticket is passed to the process running the server and that process contacts the authority to check if the ticket is valid, the authority checks the validity of the ticket, but also checks if the process is permitted to validate such a ticket ... and only processes running on COMP under System-User are allowed to validate AnyService/COMP.  User-Space processes fail with LOGIN_DENIED.

Comment: @Blazemonger:  I tried to register the SPN for a user, but then the client failed to acquire a ticket, with error UNKNOWN_ENCRYPTION.  Not sure if this is a general thing, but I had to revert to running the server under SYSTEM.

Comment: @all: the LOGIN_DENIED will also happen, if the IP of the computer running the process, doesn't properly reverse-lookup to COMP (the hostname in Service/COMP).  E.g. ftp/myhost.corp.somewhere.com will only validate, if the process that tries to accept the ticket runs on SYSTEM user of a computer which has an IP which the authority can reverse-lookup to myhost.corp.somewhere.com